# Casting string to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking around Unity code via Rider decompiler, and found something weird:

```cs
Debug.LogError((object) "EndLayoutGroup: BeginLayoutGroup must be called first.");
```

I did aware of that Unity `Debug.LogError()` accepts an `object` type as an argument, but is there any reason to cast `string` to `object`? What's the difference between the above one and

```cs
Debug.LogError("EndLayoutGroup: BeginLayoutGroup must be called first.");
```

I see no difference between these because every C# class inherits `object` type, so it will be automatically casted without any error. But I also think that there would be a reason that Unity engineers chose the way.

Comment: _via Rider decompiler_. You are viewing the code via a decompiler. So that is not how the Unity developers wrote it, it's how the decompiler is interpreting the compiled code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but my guess is that the `LogError` function takes an `object` as its parameter. It calls `ToString` on it to get a string. The authors could have provided an overload that takes a `string` but didn't bother. The decompiler, in its wisdom, includes the implicit conversion from `string` to `object` explicitly in its decompilation.

Comment: @Flydog57 That's my assumption too.

Comment: Unless there is a `Debug.LogError(string[, params])` *that acts differently*, there is no need to add the cast to avoid the more specialized overload. There _are_ some methods that act differently, including `Convert.ToString` and `Debug.WriteLine`. Perhaps the authors were expecting to avoid such a difference?

Comment: I couldn't find any string-specified overload, but I got it guys. Thinking that the decompiler added explicit conversion via interpreting the compiled code would make more sense.

Comment: I would see what dotPeek ( https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/ ) shows, as I would not expect a compiler to insert this.. I'm not sure on Rider's behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to not be decompiled right, I think this is the actual source code from [Unity's source code Reference](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/5c94c02e26a7a677b179c91be619ab902b27bd5e/Modules/IMGUI/GUILayoutUtility.cs):

```
// The matching end for BeginLayoutGroup
internal static void EndLayoutGroup()
{
    if (current.layoutGroups.Count == 0
        || Event.current == null
    )
    {
        Debug.LogError("EndLayoutGroup: BeginLayoutGroup must be called first.");

        return;
    }
    if (Event.current.type != EventType.Layout && Event.current.type != EventType.Used)
        GUIDebugger.LogLayoutEndGroup();

    current.layoutGroups.Pop();
    if (0 < current.layoutGroups.Count)
        current.topLevel = (GUILayoutGroup)current.layoutGroups.Peek();
    else
        current.topLevel = new GUILayoutGroup();
}
```